# Where can I get Debian IPv4 interface identifier?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, dhcp

I understood that nowadays Debian (I only use Debian so I don't know about other distros) no longer use MAC address to get a DHCP lease.

My machine MAC address is : 00:15:5d:40:41:41
Looking at my company's DHCP, it identifies as : 5d4041410001000124e42b1100155d404141

Question is, where on my Debian system can I get this ID ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you get a packet capture (tcpdump) of the actual DHCP request being sent? The bit you pasted doesn't look like a valid DHCP client identifier at all – as if the server is showing you an unrelated chunk of the request instead of the actual client-ID.

Comment: DHCP requests always carry the MAC address. DHCP client identifiers are also not new, but not all clients send them. Windows does. // You do not mention in your question what DHCP client you are using.

Comment: 5d4041410001000124e42b1100155d404141 is 5d, then the last 6 hex digits of the MAC address (404141), then 10001000124e42b11, and then the entire MAC address (00155d404141)

Comment: Will it always be 10001000124e42b11 ?

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` should contain the information you're looking for. The DHCP client identifier also doesn't mean that MAC addresses won't be used it's just an ID to make finding a particular device and filtering for it easier.

Debian has changed how they auto generate that ID at some point but it still can be actively set in the configuration. It might work to switch back to the old behavior by using `dhcp-client-identifier = hardware;` in the configuration.

Comment: dhclient.conf contains little to no information, and not this ID unfortunatly

Comment: But it is at least one of the places where you could set it: [dhclient.conf(5) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/dhclient.conf). Alternatively it will probably in one of your other network configuration files.

Comment: Nowhere to be found..

Comment: Are you sure it's not part of your companies DHCP server setup? The first bit of the identifier is the MAC (and repeated at the back) after all.

Comment: Windows and older Linux are ok so it seems it's from newer Debians

Comment: Did you try to actively set the configuration in the configuration file with the value you desire? See also [this](https://old.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/ca5vjb/dhcp_identifiers_changed_on_upgrade_to_buster/) and [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/dhcp-client-id-on-debian-10-a-4175663329/).